# In azure data factory need to update a object in json file with the given condition

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a json

```
{
  "name" :"job", 
  "lastupdate": "2023-09-15", 
  "schedule":
  { 
    "table" :
    [
      { 
        "tablename":"mani",
        "time":"2023-09-15"
      }
```

like this 10tables are there according to the given input table the time in the particular table block needs to update and the above lastupdate need to update to current time.

I have tried but I wasn't able to get the scenario.

Comment: Can you provide your pipeline JSON? any error or blockers? and sample input and expected output?

Comment: {
  "name" :"job", 
  "lastupdate": "2023-09-15", 
  "schedule":
  { 
    "table" :
    [
      { 
        "tablename":"mani",
        "time":"2023-09-15"
      },{"tablename":"nani",
        "time":"2023-09-15"}

Comment: you want to update all the dateswith current date?

Comment: No we have to pass the table name  for the particular table the time needs to update and in the above column last update that needs to be update for any table

Comment: Anyone have any sugestion how to do..

Answer (score 0):

**To update an object in Json file with the given condition.** follow below steps:

- To update Json object, you need to use data flow activity Load the Json source in data flow with the similar data (used by me):
  [image]
- Now flatten all the array by using flatten transformation.
  [image]
  Data preview:
  [image]
- Create data flow parameter to store the table name as below.
  [image]
- Now change the date based on condition as **if it matches with the tablename.**
  with condition as

```
time - iif(tablename == $tablenameinput ,toString(currentDate()), toString(time))
lastupdate - iif(tablename == $tablenameinput ,toString(currentDate()), toString(lastupdate))
```

[image]

- Now with the aggregation transformation again create an array of tablename and time columns.
  [image]
  [image]
  Data preview:
  [image]
- Now using another derived column transformation **create subcolumn  table under schedule column.**
  [image]
  [image]
  Data preview:
  [image]- Using sink transformation load the data into sink file with below setting and set your output filename
  [image]
- Now for the parameter we created in dataflow pas the pipeline parameter tablename.
  [image]
  [image]

So, after running the pipeline the table name you prove it will update time for it only.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution is there any way without using dataflow ?

Comment: To manipulate the data we use dataflow activity.

Comment: Hi pratik,   Can we do that with lookup and foreach

Comment: Thank you very much for the above solution. I have tried with data flow it's working fine....but taking so much time so

Comment: For data transformation We can use only data flow, with lookup and foreach it's not possible to transform the data. For data flows performance and tuning you can refer this  [Documnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance)

Comment: I'm from hyderabad, Could you please give me any contact like insta,telegram or email...i want to connect with you once

Comment: Its updating but .Its generating outer object twice

Comment: which object can you add it in question?

Comment: I have a pic but how to send here

Comment: add output you are getting in txt format

Comment: Its in office network i cant able to add text

Comment: I have taken pic and highlighted the generating extra lines and updated table is getting out side the arrray

Comment: In aggregate data preview you are getting sinle row but im getting 2 job rows

Comment: have you grouped by name and lastupdate column?

Comment: Its solved thank you pratik in derived column i have changed the expression